# Rows to single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I  would like to get the desired output marked in green

[image]

the data points for each id get put into a single cell

Basically take all the events that have happened with A and attach it in the same order

Comment: Also add more information such as table names, and what have you tried? And how do we know what order the items in the event column should be displayed in? It looks alphabetical, but is it?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: But why do you want to do that?!? Seems like a pretty bad idea to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: i'm doing it to see which id have a common sequence to prove that the event flow is random

Comment: How do i delete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Stuff Function:**

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table(
    ID INT,
    EVENT VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES
(1,'A'),
(1,'A'),
(1,'C'),
(2,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(2,'C')

SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.ID,
    STUFF
    (
         (SELECT '' + convert(varchar(10), T2.EVENT, 120)
          FROM @tblTest T2
          where T1.ID = T2.ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
    , 1, 0, '')  AS EVENT
FROM @tblTest T1
```

Comment: , 1, 0, '') the parentheses are missing

Comment: i have answer after test in my system, no any such error

Comment: I know what it is :) There is no need to use it here. It is often used when you need to separate values coming `FOR XML PATH ('')`, but here it has no use - no separators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FOR XML:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            ID,
            (SELECT [EVENT] +''
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE ID = y.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) as [EVENT]
FROM YourTable y
```

Output:

```
ID  EVENT
1   AABCD
2   AABBCC
```

Comment: I don't understand why you haven't tried my solution? it is simple and clear, the one you choose as answer is a copy of my answer with STUFF (which has no use here). The other one that uses temp table and is copy of my answer is upvoted...

Answer (score 1):

You can use UDF to do so as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
id INT,
col CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'a');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'b');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'c');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'d');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,'e');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,'f');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3,'g');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4,'h');
```

The UDF (User defined function) -

```
USE [t]
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConcatenateCols(@Id INT)

RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RtnStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @RtnStr = COALESCE(@RtnStr + '','') + col
FROM dbo.t
WHERE id = @Id AND col > ''
RETURN @RtnStr

END
GO
```

Finally the query and result:

```
SELECT id, dbo.ConcatenateCols(id) AS Cols -- UDF - ConcatenateCols(id)
FROM t GROUP BY Id
```

[image: concatenate_col]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(Id INt,Event Nvarchar(25))
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT 1,
       'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,
       'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,
       'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,
       'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,
       'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'C'
SELECT DISTINCT ID,

  (SELECT [EVENT] +''
   FROM #temp
   WHERE ID = y.ID
     FOR XML PATH('') ) AS [EVENT]
FROM #temp y
```

Comment: Copy of my answer.